# How to make iron-data-table scroll document?

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component

I understand that `<iron-data-table>` is based on `<iron-list>`, so I tried to set the attribute of the table's inner `<iron-list>` like this:

```
$('iron-list').removeAttr("on-scroll");
$('iron-list').attr("scroll-target","document");
```

I also tried to select the list this way `document.querySelector('iron-list')`
But none of them works, so what is the correct way to make it scroll the page instead of scrolling the table itself?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use querySelector. Get the element by using querySelector and use setAttribute function. For example

```
this.querySelector('#id').setAttribute("scroll-target", 'document');
```

To remove attribute, use .removeAttribute()